# Core forum hook_menu_local_tasks_alter() override

Tags: 7, hooks

i'm trying to implement lightweight topic tracker for core forums (tracking new topics and comments on main forum view).

I'd like to override `forum_forum_load()` method, but core forums calls `forum_forum_load()` method inside of a `forum_menu_local_tasks_alter()` and besides my overridden `mymodule_forum_load()` and `mymodule_local_tasks_alter()` it'll still call core forums own `forum_forum_load()` method making 2x more queries (2 x Amount of forums, in this case 28x2).

I replaced forum load function call inside of `forum_menu_local_tasks_alter()` with my own function and seems like it's working just fine, but I don't want to mess with the core, so I'd know if there is other way to prevent that behaviour.

I tried some other forum extending modules and they all have exactly same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in not wanting to mess with core; it makes things tricky when you're trying to update to a new version of Drupal. You have to maintain patch files which may break with new core code and it just gets messy.

Fortunately Drupal does provide a method to handle exactly what you're after.

In Drupal 7 hook implementations are alterable, so you can use [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) to stop `forum_menu_local_tasks_alter()` from ever running:

```
function MYMODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'menu_local_tasks_alter') {
    unset($implementations['forum']);
  }
}
```

You'll need to copy the code from `forum_menu_local_tasks_alter()` and put it in your own `mymodule_local_tasks_alter()` function, and just replace the call to `forum_forum_load()` with the call to your `mymodule_forum_load()` function.